# irreduciblity in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that the polynomial $g(x,y,z)=z^{1000}+x+\sum_{i=1}^{999} x^iy^iz^i $ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$.

I think to use Eisenstein's Criteria but I cant..? Somebody help me?

Comment: If the sum would be from $10$ to $99$, Eisenstein would immediately kill this one and it would not get that nasty. Is there a typo?

Comment: @MooS Sorry I wrote wrongly, now I editted. The sum is from 1 to 999

Comment: And the exponent of $z$ in the first summand?

Comment: @MooS nope.. the question is correct now..

Comment: After you replaced the $100$ with a $1000$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now it is an easy one:

Interpret $g$ as an polynomial in $z$ over the factorial ring $\mathbb C[x,y]$ and use Eisenstein with respect to the prime $x \in \mathbb C[x,y]$

Comment: I choose p=x then apply Eisenstein's Criteria but it is useful?
I mean;
Consider $C[x,y,z]$ as a $C[x,y][z]$ then coefficients are $x^i$ and $y^i$ x is irreliviant in $C[x,y]$ choose p=x then Eisenstein's Criteria say us g is irredicuble..
But I think that something missing.. My solution is correct?

Comment: What you should think about (once in your life!), is the following: Irreducibility in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ and $\mathbb (C[x,y])[z]$ is the same. Nothing else left to do here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. This is new subject for me.. I was confused sometimes